# How to update listview inside fragment not in oncreateview method

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a method **«Start()»** that reads the document and writes the data to the **listview**

This method is in the fragment that is used in the **ViewPager**

I need this method to be able to display the listview because I need to call this method in other actions from which I will not be able to display the **listview**

**Fragment**

```
public class classWednesday extends Fragment {
    private ListView lvMain;
    private List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HelpAdapter> products = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer num = 0;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && (getActivity()!=null)) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("Day","Wednesday.txt" );
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.wednesday, container,false);
        Start();
        lvMain = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.lvWednesday);
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),products);
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"dsaasdasasdhasuidgasiuygausgdgydgas",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains("Wednesday")) {
            ImageButton imageButton = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonWednesday);
            if (settings.getBoolean("Wednesday", true))
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
            else
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

        }
        return viewGroup;
    }
    public void Start() {
        products.clear();
        try {
            FileInputStream read = getActivity().openFileInput("Wednesday.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(read);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String temp_read;
            while ((temp_read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                num ++;
                products.add(new HelpAdapter(num + ")", temp_read));

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            reader.close();
            read.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ignore) {    
        }
        num = 0;    
    }
}
```

P.S. If add

```
lvMain = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvWednesday);
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),products);         
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in **Start ()** method

Then,

> lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

returns **null**

Comment: which one return null?

Comment: listview "lvMain" when you add new records here `lvMain = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvWednesday);` it becomes null. Returns null when the application loads `lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 0):

Use View instead of ViewGroup

```
View viewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wednesday, container,false);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is that supposed to help me?

Comment: onCreateView()
The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

Please refer the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)